# Add wildcard to the end of a URL after a specific word

Tags: regex, angular, url, url-routing, wildcard

I have a URL that looks like this:

```
https://localhost:8080/user/login
```

However, there is the ability to manually append query parameters so that the URL can look like this.

```
https://localhost:8080/user/login?ten=123456
```

So I need a wildcard with which everything is taken after the word 'login'.

My URLs are defined in within a constant object like this:

```
export const Constants = {
    routing: {
      home: '/',
      userLogin: '/user/login',
}
```

..and are used like this:

```
const routing = Constants.routing;
const url = this.routing.userLogin
```

Answer (score 2):

Naviagte to your url with the `Router.navigate` in your component

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router"

constructor(private router : Router){} 

navigateToUserLogin(){
     this.router.navigate([url], { queryParams: { ten: 123456 } });
}
```

You can use `ActivatedRoute` in your user-login component to extract the query params of the url

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit(){
   this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params=> { console.log(params); });
}
```

Comment: I already use the router and make the following comparison to see if the user is currently on the login screen:

this.router.url === this.routing.userLogin.

Now it is the case that the user can manually append a tenant as a query parameter to the URL.

For this reason, these manually added parameters should also be considered and the URL evaluated as if the query parameters are not present.

So my comparison above should look like this: this.router.url === this.routing.userLogin || this.router.url === this.routing.userLoginWithTenant

Answer (score 0):

I don't now if i unstand your problem?

A regex to extract everything after the word 'login' would be:

```
(?<=login).*$
```

How to apply in Component:

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    let regex = new RegExp("(?<=login).*$");
    const matches = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(matches.length>0){
      this.href=matches[0];
    }
  }
```

For routing with queryparams in angular you can use NavigationExtras with the queryParams property:

```
router.navigate(["user", "login"], { queryParams: { ten: "123456" } });
```

And using router link

```
<a [routerLink]="["user", "login"]" [queryParams]="{ ten: '123456' }">Login</a>
```

Comment: I already use the router and make the following comparison to see if the user is currently on the login screen:

this.router.url === this.routing.userLogin.

Now it is the case that the user can manually append a tenant as a query parameter to the URL.

For this reason, these manually added parameters should also be considered and the URL evaluated as if the query parameters are not present.

So my comparison above should look like this: this.router.url === this.routing.userLogin || this.router.url === this.routing.userLoginWithTenant